# Proof of Euler's Totient Function is correct without CRT?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

I don't know how to translate my following informal proof into a formal one:

Observation: The product $(1-{1\over a})(1-{1\over b})$ means that counting from $1$, a multiple of $a$ is encounter and it is excluded from the total portion.(same idea for $b$) But then a multiple of $ab$ will be excluded twice every $ab$ numbers, so I add the portion back: $(-{1\over a})(-{1\over b})={1\over ab}$.

Thus $\phi(n)=n\prod_{p|n}(1-{1\over p})$.

Is this method acceptable?

The proof from Wikipedia prove that $\phi(n)$ is multiplicative, my idea is that since the inclusion-exclusion formula $(1-{1\over a})(1-{1\over b})$ is multiplicative, so to prove totient function is equivalent to prove why inclusion-exclusion formula work.

Comment: I have no idea what the sentence "every $a$ numbers I skip a multiple of $a$" means.

Comment: You can formalize this by proof with an inclusion-explusion argument.

Comment: It is not an informal proof. It is just a random collection of words. "The product ... means that ..." does not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that $p_i$ are prime factors of $n$.

View  $\left(1-\frac{1}{p_i} \right)$ is the fraction  of numbers from $1$ to $n$ that are not multiples of $p_i$.

$\prod_{p|n}\left(1-\frac1p \right)$ is the fraction of numbers from $1$ to $n$ that are not multiples of any of the prime factors.

Hence $$\phi(n)=n\prod_{p|n}\left(1-\frac1p \right) $$

Notice that if there are $m$ prime factors, we have

$$\prod_{p|n}\left( 1-\frac1p\right)=1+\sum_{l=1}^m \sum_{p_1 < \ldots < p_l|n}(-1)^l \prod_{j=1}^l\frac{1}{p_j}$$

which is the inclusion-exclusion procedure that you tried to describe.

Answer (score 0):

**I use the same idea of build a power set $P(A)$ of a given set $A$:**

Consider $(1-\frac{1}{a})$ as a set containing two subsets: $\{1\}, \{-\frac{1}{a}\}$, where $\{1\}$ is analogous to empty set $\emptyset$.

Next consider the result of multiply it by $(1-\frac{1}{b})$, then we get $$\begin{align}(1-\frac{1}{a})(1-\frac{1}{b})&=(1-\frac{1}{a})+\left[-\frac{1}{b}(1-\frac{1}{a})\right]\\&=(1-\frac{1}{a})+(-\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{ab}),\end{align}$$

and this can be seen as adding $-\frac{1}{b}$ into every existing subset. Again multiply it by $(1-\frac{1}{c})$ we get $$\begin{align}\left[(1-\frac{1}{a})+(-\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{ab})\right](1-\frac{1}{c})=&\left[(1-\frac{1}{a})+(-\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{ab})\right]\\&+\left[(-\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{ac})+(\frac{1}{bc}-\frac{1}{abc})\right].\end{align}$$

Assume $n$ has $m$ distinct prime factors, then:

> $\color{blue}{\textrm{For every $i\in[0,m]$}}$ and consider $\color{red}{\textrm{all $\binom{m}{i}$ combinations, the product of these $i$ prime factors}}$ can be found above and its sign is the same as $(-1)^i$.

is actually equivalent to the following inclusion-exclusion principle formula, where $S_i$ compute the sum of fraction of $i$-factors-divisible numbers $\le n$:

$$\color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^m}(-1)^i\color{red}{S_i}.$$ Thus the formula $\prod_{p|n}(1-\frac{1}{p})$ is correct.