# A connection between Fibonacci numbers and the golden ratio

Tags: elementary-number-theory, soft-question, fibonacci-numbers, totient-function, golden-ratio

I'm very interested in studying number theory and I post an other conjecture between the golden ratio and Fibonacci numbers.
N.B: it is well known that is a link between the golden ratio and Fibonacci numbers. I just want to know if my proof already exists in the literature.

---

**Conjecture**:

I'm looking for a formula between Fibonacci numbers and the golden ratio $\varphi$. The formula is:

$$\varphi(n) = n \cdot \prod_{p | n} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right).$$

where the product is taken over all distinct prime factors $p$ of $n$.

**Proof**

If we let $n$ be a power of $2$, say $n = 2^k$ ($k$ is an integer $> 1$), then we can simplify this formula further using the fact that $1 - \frac{1}{2} = 1/2$.

Applying this identity repeatedly, we get:

$$\varphi(2^k) = 2^k \cdot \prod_{i=0}^k (1 - \frac{1}{2}) = 2^{k-1},$$

where $\prod_{i=0}^k$ denotes the product of $(k+1)$ terms, and we have used the fact that there are $k+1$ distinct prime factors of $2^k$, namely $2^0$, $2^1$, ..., $2^k$.

Now, we can use the fact that the limit of the ratio of consecutive Fibonacci numbers approaches the golden ratio as the sequence progresses. Specifically, if we let $F_n$ denote the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number, then we have:

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} {\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}} = \varphi$$

Finally, we can combine these results to obtain a formula relating Fibonacci numbers to the golden ratio in terms of Fibonacci numbers:

$$\varphi(2^k) = 2^{k-1}= \left(\frac{F_k}{\sqrt{5}}\right)^{\frac{1}{\varphi}}$$

This formula expresses the value of $\varphi(2^k)$ in terms of both the totient function and the golden ratio, with the Fibonacci numbers serving as an intermediate link between the two.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what all the downvote are all about. You have a well-formed conjecture with a nice proof.

Your conjecture is indeed correct. To answer your question: this is already well-known and can be found on the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Computing_Euler%27s_totient_function) for the Euler Totient function.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3801407/proof-of-eulers-totient-function-is-correct-without-crt?noredirect=1) is another question with the given proof.

I'm not aware & couldn't find any "well-known" proof using the technique you give.